# jquery datatables img in aoCoulumn

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm getting the data from a database but one of them is an image file path like this '~\images\food.png' but i want to but it in an img tag so it can show the image not the path. Some one help please, Thanks in advance.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
     load();
 });
 function load() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ParentCategoryManagment.aspx/PopulateCategories",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: "{}",
         dataType: "json",
         success: AjaxSucceeded,
         error: AjaxFailed
     });
 }
 function AjaxSucceeded(respone) {

     var json = jQuery.parseJSON(respone.d);

     if (typeof oTable == 'undefined') {
         oTable = $('#tblData').dataTable({
             'aaData': json,
             'aoColumns':
                [
                    { "mDataProp": "Id" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Name" },
                    { "mDataProp": "ImagePath" },
                    { "mDataProp": null, "sDefaultContent": '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>' },
                    { "mDataProp": null, "sDefaultContent": '<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>' }
                ]
         });
     }
     else {

         oTable.fnClearTable(0);
         oTable.fnAddData(json);
         oTable.fnDraw();

     }
 }
 function AjaxFailed(result) {
     alert('Ajax Failed');
 }
```

Comment: hello need info u available for chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22475/chattable

Comment: I don't understand your question. Add more info.

Comment: sajawikio i can't chat becuase i need 20 rep

Comment: o yeah i forgot about that

Comment: im populating a table with jquery ajax but one of my row is an image path. i wish that image path to change it to an img tag

Comment: i figured out how to use i think hold on

Comment: Ok i made your question into a demo with a demo JSON object - now see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HPdVH/2/ - tell me what it is wrong with ImagePath in more detail that you want to know how to address.

Comment: hmm i might know what you mean already let me see...

Comment: ye like that but the i'm actually showing the image as  '~\images\food.png' in the cell, is there a way to change that to <img> tag and the src change to the this  '~\images\food.png'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See JSFIDDLE DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/HPdVH/5/

You need to go through each of your image paths and turn them to images. In your case it always seems to be the third table column so you could do this after your table is loaded via ajax:

```
 $("tr").each(function(){
         $(this).children("td")
                .eq(2)
                .html("<img src='" + $(this).html() + "'/>");
 })
```

Comment: wow thanks it worked, but it only worked for the first row XD

Comment: a better idea might be this: modify json object where it says "Imagepath" using javascript to add the image tag BEFORE table is populated, then populate the table with the json

Comment: $("tr").each(function () {
                    $(this).children("td").eq(2).each(function () {
                        var k = $(this).html();
                        $(this).html("<img src='" + k + "'/>");
                    });
                });

Comment: i edited my code - lol we figured it out at exactly the same time i just edited it and you commented - glad i could help!